# c# - Como hacer una llamada POST desde mi consola hacia mi controladora?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, consola

Estoy realizando un login desde mi consola y tengo que llamar a una accion de mi controladora.

Esta accion lo que hace es que : **si ingreso el usuario y clave correctos me devuelve un TOKEN**

Yo quiero hacer el llamado hacia esta accion y mostrar lo que seria el token en mi consola.

**Actualizacion**
Gracias a los comentarios de la pregunta he llegado a este punto, pero sigue sin darme resultado, me parece que me hace falta algo mas!

Cuando me pide los datos (user y clave) se cierra la consola, a no ser que ponga un Console.ReadLine();

Inserto mi codigo de consola:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
        obtengoToken();
        Console.ReadLine();
  }

     static async void obtengoToken()
    {
        loginRequest login = new loginRequest();

        //primero usa sin read line estable los valores en codigo duro solo para prueas rapidas y despues ya lee los datos desde console
        Console.WriteLine("ingrese usuario: ");
        login.Username = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("ingrese clave: ");
        login.Password = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("      ");

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(login);
        var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var url = "http://localhost:49830/api/login/autenticar";
        var client = new HttpClient();

        var response = await client.PostAsync(url, data);

        string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
```

Inserto codigo de controladora:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [Route("autenticar")]
    public IHttpActionResult Autenticar(loginRequest login)
    {
        if (login == null)
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

        //TODO: Validate credentials Correctly, this code is only for demo !!
        bool password = (login.Password == "123456");
        if (password)
        {
            var token = TokenGenerator.GenerateTokenJwt(login.Username);
            return Json(token);
        }
        else
        {
            return Unauthorized();
        }
    }
```

Como puedo solucionar esto? Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utiliza lo siguiente,

```
 static async Task Main(string[] args)
            {
               loginRequest login= new loginRequest(); 

                  //primero usa sin read line estable los valores en codigo duro solo para prueas rapidas y despues ya lee los datos desde console
                     Console.WriteLine("ingrese usuario: ");
                login.usuario = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("ingrese clave: ");
                login.Password= Console.ReadLine();
                 Console.WriteLine("      ");

                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(login);
                var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                var url = "http://localhost:49830/api/login/autenticar";
                using var client = new HttpClient();

                var response = await client.PostAsync(url, data);

                string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                Console.WriteLine(result);
                Console.Read();
            }
```

Comment: gracias, pero cuando creao el metodo static async task Main me patea porque "El programa no contiene ningun metodo ;main' estatico adecuado para el punto de entrada"

Comment: Intenta Cambiando task a void

Comment: Era esta la solucion : en la url tenia el nombre del action en minuscula! Gracias